# `The group is rebalancing, so a rejoin is needed` error causes message to be consumed more than once

Tags: kafkajs

I have an edge in Kafkajs consumer, where at times I get a rebalancing error:

```
The group is rebalancing, so a rejoin is needed
[Connection] Response Heartbeat(key: 12, version: 3)
The group is rebalancing, so a rejoin is needed
[Runner] The group is rebalancing, re-joining
```

Then, once the consumer group is rebalanced, the last message that was processed is processed again, as a commit did not occur due to the error.

Kafka consumer initialzation code:

```
import { Consumer, Kafka } from 'kafkajs';


const kafkaInstance = new Kafka({
      clientId: 'some_client_id',
      brokers: ['brokers list'],
      ssl: true
    });

const kafkaConsumer = kafkaInstance.consumer({ groupId: 'some_consumer_group_id });
await kafkaConsumer.connect();
await kafkaConsumer.subscribe({ topic: 'some_topic', fromBeginning: true });

await kafkaConsumer.run({
      autoCommit: false, // cancel auto commit in order to control committing
      eachMessage: ... some processing function
});
```

I increased `sessionTimeout` & `heartbeatInteval` to higher values and different combinations, but still under heavy message load, I get the error.

I added a call to `heartbeat` function inside `eachMessage` function, which seems to resolve the issue.

But was wondering if it's considered as "good practice" or is there something else I can do on the consumer side in order to prevent such error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a call to `heartbeat` function inside of `eachMessage` function, which seems to resolve the issue.